# the multi-part identifier "my email" could not be bound

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

When I try to signup in the web site I get the message

> the multi-part identifier "my email" could not be bound.

```cs
if (Request.Form["send"] != null)
{
    string email = Request.Form["email"];
    string password = Request.Form["password"];
    string conPassword = Request.Form["conPassword"];

    if (!password.Equals(conPassword))
    {
        //
    }
    else
    {
        string connectionString = //my database connection
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        string query = "insert into users(email,password) values("+email +","+password+")";    

        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        con.Open();
        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();    
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use proper parameters and strong types. Appending user values like that is problematic (you need to surround it with single quotes, and double up any single quotes in the value), and leaves your code ripe for SQL injection.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

that's because there is a "." in email,use '    ':

```
 string query = "insert into users(email,password) values('"+email +"',"+password+")";
```